Can shapes e.g. triangles and circles, be added?
Addition, subtraction etc. seem like basic operations we try/test often. My son wondered if shapes can be added. My guess is that they can be e.g. if we convert shapes to algebraic representation, we can add them. However, the new algebraic entity might (or might not) have an intuitive shape.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... and kudos to your son for his mathy inquisitiveness! :)  There is an important notion of shape addition via something called the Minkowski sum. Basically, it's what you get by adding (in the vector sense) each point in one shape to each point in the other shape. The Wikipedia entry isn't really the best introductory description of this idea (nor is this comment, for that matter), but you now have the basis to do a web search for resources that  make sense to yourself and your son. ... Good luck!

Well you could regard shapes as subsets of the plane and define addition as set union.  However, most of the time, the result won't have a nice name.
$Square1 + Square2$ might be a square (if one is inside the other), it might be a rectangle, it might be various odd shapes, or two separate squares.
I don't think that anyone has found this sufficiently interesting to study.
Other possibilities exist but I don't know any that are more interesting.
It is nice that he is exploring ideas.

I did not know the Minkowski sum mentioned by Blue in a comment.
